# How can I fetch documents in batches from CosmosDB and process them?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to fetch documents from CosmosDB and then do a foreach loop on the documents returned, I am doing it as follows

```
var productListFromHAPI = 
    await CosmosDb.GetProductDataFromHAPI(brand, deployedCountry,
         primaryLocale, secondaryLocale, _rawDataContainer, log);

var finalListOfObjects = new List<StorelensItemModel_V3>();

foreach (var storeVariantToInsert in productListFromHAPI) { processing here }
```

The problem is that GetProductDataFromHAPI returns millions of documents and the host no matter how large I make is running out of resources.

How can I split this up so that I can fetch and process 1000 documents at the time? I know I can use select top 1000 etc but how do I then know that the second round I am not fetching the same items again?

I tried to use offset and limit as well but I could not get it to work

Pagination does not seem to be a good fit for this use case.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you would want to return millions of documents. Plus, there is a 4MB response payload limit, and then you'd need to paginate through to subsequent chunks of return values - not sure why that would cause you to run out of resources, since you can't return millions of documents at a time. As for LIMIT and OFFSET - you haven't included any of that in your question, nor what issue you ran into (you just said you couldn't get it to work). Please edit to be specific.

Comment: Can you explain what is `CosmosDb.GetProductDataFromHAPI` ? Is that some implementation of your application? Are you consuming some library? Those APIs do not exist in the official Cosmos DB SDKs.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta yes its just a wrapper for the cosmosDB SDK that creates the query for the documents, I am just trying to figure out how I can paginate through the ansers as receiving them in one go is to much

Comment: If you can share the wrapper code we can help point you on the right direction. The Cosmos SDK query iterators return results by pages along with a continuation token.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta yes your latest comment sent me in the right direction I am now able to page through n items at the time by using the continuationToken it was very easy to implement after I read your comment, if you make it an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a wrapper `GetProductDataFromHAPI` that is calling the Cosmos SDK underneath.

The Cosmos SDK FeedIterators allow you to paginate, consuming one page of results at a time:

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.feediterator-1?view=azure-dotnet#examples

```
using (FeedIterator<StorelensItemModel_V3> feedIterator = this.Container.GetItemQueryIterator<StorelensItemModel_V3>(
    "query"))
{
    while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        FeedResponse<StorelensItemModel_V3> response = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();
        
        // You can yield the response for an upper layer to be consumed and pass the ContinuationToken to use the next time you want to continue the query
    }
}
```

As a side note, keep in mind the performance tips when constructing and executing queries: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/performance-tips-query-sdk?tabs=v3&pivots=programming-language-csharp